# You have 24 objects divided into 6 groups of 4. You randomly choose 1 object from each group. How many potential combinations are there?

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm a personal trainer putting together a "build you own workout" template. I have 24 exercises arranged into 6 groups of 4. You choose 1 exercise from each group to build a full-body workout.

How many potential combinations - workouts - are there?

Comment: I think where you wrote "randomly" you mean "arbitrarily". There doesn't seem to be any random element in the question.

Comment: @joriki yes you're right. I did mean "arbitrarily".

Comment: Are the 6 groups fixed or you want to know the result considering all the possible 6 groups of 4 elements which can be made?

Comment: Are we to assume the partition of 24 exercises into "6 groups of 4" is given, a fixed selection?  Or did you mean to count the outcomes that are possible (1 exercise for each group) for all possible groupings of exercises?

Comment: @ECL the groups are fixed

Comment: @hardmath yes, the groups are fixed. An exercise in group 1 is always in group 1

Comment: There's an edit button under the question; you can fix it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the 6 groups are fixed the number is simply $4^6 = 4096$.